# How do I call up an image tag?

Tags: php, if-statement

How do I call up an image tag?

I have different images on my site in img tags.

I would like the images to swap at a sertain point, so I would like to use a sentence like this one:

```
if (share_btn.png == "share_btn.png"){
    share_btn.png = 'share2_btn.png'
}
```

I basically want to check if the image is image A or image B at that point, and if it's image A, then swap it to image B.

I guess I have to have a name or id or something on the img src so that I can call it up in the if sentence.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Call it up in *what*? Swap it where? What programming language are you using? HTML doesn't have `if` statements.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using PHP.

I want to call up the img src in the if condition.

I have a page where users can upload text in a text field. When the user hits the sumbit button, the site refreshes. When the site loads again, I want an image to be swaped.

I can't just swap the images when someone clicks on the submit button, because the page refreshes, and it loads the old image again.

So I would like to use the if-statement right after the refresh-comand, so that the page refreshes with the new image

Comment: In that case, why not post a variable when the submit button is pressed, and check for it in $_POST when the page loads. If the var is present, use the appropriate image. If the user enters the page through the URL or otherwise, the image will be a default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name this file yourpage.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="yourpage.php">
<input type="hidden" name="issubmitted" value="submitted" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</from>

<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['issubmitted']))
{
 print "<img src='share2_btn.png' />";
}
else
{
 print "<img src='share_btn.png' />";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant! It worked. The only thing is that I have to controll where the images appear. Can I use "print" to print a div tag from css?

Comment: Nevermind, I just moved the print to where it sould be in the code, and it kinda worked!